# Very similar errors in WordPress log file

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, error-log, wordpress-plugin-creation

```
[24-Jun-2021 04:32:21 Asia/Tehran] Error Duplicate entry '567411' for key 'PRIMARY' In the database WordPress for commands INSERT INTO `ua_options` (`option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES ('cron', 'a:2:{i:1624492941;a:1:{s:16:\"wp_update_themes\";a:1:{s:32:\"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a\";a:3:{s:8:\"schedule\";s:10:\"twicedaily\";s:4:\"args\";a:0:{}s:8:\"interval\";i:43200;}}}s:7:\"version\";i:2;}', 'yes') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `option_name` = VALUES(`option_name`), `option_value` = VALUES(`option_value`), `autoload` = VALUES(`autoload`) Made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), do_action('init'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, wp_schedule_update_checks, wp_schedule_event, _set_cron_array, update_option, add_option
```

hi this error has been found in a large amount in the WordPress error-log file of my site. On the other hand, the consumption of the host CPU has also increased a lot. What is the problem?

Comment: 1) backup everything. 2) `repair table ua_options`

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Comment: please explain more about your problem/expectation from the above code snippet to help your question be understandable.